# Puppet - get list of packages and versions

Tags: puppet, package-management, asset-management

Is it possible to tell puppet to compile a catalog for one (or all) node(s) and save that particular data somewhere?

I'm specifically interested in getting all needed packages and their versions per node, but a general approach for getting any data is also suitable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This original answer is now out of date. The updated command for Puppet 3.x is:

```
puppet resource package
```

---

If you're looking for all the packages and versions installed on a node regardless of whether they're installed by Puppet or not, the following command is built in and can be run on any Puppet node:

`ralsh package`

This will output the data in a Puppet manifest form to stdout.

Ralsh will work for any resource type that has the `instances` method implemented (users, groups, etc.).

If you're looking to centrally inspect the YAML catalog for all resources defined in Puppet manifests, your Puppetmaster already caches this information in `/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml/catalog` and you just need to parse it with your YAML parser of choice. The Puppet Inventory Service that was introduced fairly recently may also be a good option for you; you can make do with storeconfigs if you're running on an older version like 0.25.x.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it doesn't allow for multiple versions of the same package, as is common with the kernel package on Red Hat-based distros.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question: The command lists the currently _installed_ packages, not the packages required by Puppet.  I'm interested in a list of the latter to feed it to `rpmorphan`.

Comment: @TimLandscheidt, are you asking about the full list of `package` resources that Puppet lists in the catalog for a node? Unless you feel up to parsing the cached catalog, your best bet would be to query PuppetDB. The query API is available [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/1.5/api/query/v3/resources.html]).

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Finally got around to installing PuppetDB, and indeed it does what I want.  I can query for all package resources that have "ensure" not equal to "absent" for a specific host, and use the JSON result to feed a list to rpmorphan.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is the sort of thing that mcollective was built to do.  Specifically, the package provider for mcollective: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/mcollective-plugins/wiki/AgentPackage

This completely skips puppet, and doesn't even require that puppet is installed.